# Page not found (404) The current path, register/POST, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django, post, pycharm, django-urls

i am creating a blog via Django on the PyCharm editor and i have come across a 404 error.

This is the full error message:

```
Using the URLconf defined in django_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
register/ [name='register']
[name='blog-home']
about/ [name='blog-about']
The current path, register/POST, didn't match any of these.
```

This is the **urls.py** folder in the main project folder:
the 'users' and 'views' below underline in red

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from *users* import *views* as user_views  

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),

]
```

This is my **views.py** in my **users** folder:

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages  # to display a message if the form data is correct

```
    def register(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':  # if the request is a 'post' then it will create a form
            form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
                return redirect('blog-home')
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()  # anything not a post request it will create a blank form
        return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

And the html file **register** in the **users** directory within the **templates** folder:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class=content-section">
    <form action="Post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today!!!</legend>
            {{ form }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">Already have an account? <a class="ml-2" href="#"></a>
        </small>

    </div>


</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

This is the **admin.py** from the **blog** directory:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

This is the structure:

```
C:.
├───blog
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───static
│   │   └───blog
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───blog
│   └───__pycache__
├───django_project
│   └───__pycache__
└───users
    ├───migrations
    │   └───__pycache__
    ├───templates
    │   └───users
    └───__pycache__
```

I have tried editing the code etc but not changes occur.
if you need further code let me know
Please help, Thanks

Comment: You haven't shown your template, but it looks like you might have `action="POST"` instead of `method="POST"` in your `<form>` tag

Comment: its already saved as action, i have added the template now

Comment: I haven't used any javascript in this project

Comment: any idea why my 'users' and 'views' when imported are underlined in red in my url.py?

Comment: Also does 'register/POST' do?

Comment: `action="Post"` tells the browser to submit the form to the URL `Post`. This gets added to the current URL `/register/` (because `Post` doesn't start with a slash) to give `register/Post` from the error message (I'm ignoring the diffent capitalisation of `Post` and `POST`). Change the template to use `<form method="post">`.

Comment: I changed it to 'post', the same error shows:  **"The current path, register/post, didn't match any of these."**

Comment: If you hover over the red underlines it probably says "Unresolved reference". This means that PyCharm can't find the modules. The code is probably fine, otherwise you'd get an import error when you try to run the code. You should be able to change your PyCharm configuration to fix the issue, but I can't help you with that.

Comment: You need to change `action` to `method` as well.

Comment: I tried changing it but the same error occurs

Comment: I should be doing this on my register.html file right?

Comment: You might have to restart your server and refresh the `register` page in your browser after saving the changes.

Comment: Yes, that worked!

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Was stuck on this for 2 hours

Comment: Post the answer and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your form has `action="Post"`, which is causing the browser to access a URL that doesn't exist.

```
<form action="Post">
```

You should use `method="post"` to get the brower to use a POST request for the form.

```
<form method="post">
```